# Schedule Purge Queue Message

Tags: powershell, command-line, message-queue

Is there a way for me to schedule a Purge Queue Message Task. I wondered if there are some script that can purge Queue Message. If there are script for that I can simply set a task scheduler to periodically purge queue Message.
My environment set like this.

```
.\Private Queues\my queues name\Queue messages [Queue Message are queued here]
.\Private Queues\my queues name\retry [when above Queue failed it is queue here]
.\Private Queues\my queues name\poison [when retry reach certain amount]
```

so my intention is to remove the poison queue.
For now I purge it manually, so right now I was looking to automate purge Queue Message

Answer (score 0):

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Messaging
$queuename = ".\private$\poison"

if ([System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::Exists($queuename)) {
        $queue = New-Object -TypeName "System.Messaging.MessageQueue"
        $queue.Path = $queuename
        $messagecount = $queue.GetAllMessages().Length 
        $queue.Purge() 
        Write-Output "Purged $messagecount messages from $queuename."
    }
```